# WPF, user control, not found closing tag

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I write some WPF application with my own user control. Here is XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="wpfUserCtrl.Controls.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" Margin="0,0,0,197">
        <Label Name="lblText">My own text</Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And I put it in MainWindow.xaml, here is code

```
<Window x:Class="wpfUserCtrl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:wpfUserCtrl.Controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ctrl:MyControl Name="sad"></ctrl:MyControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I get warning: "Closing tag for element  was not found". Why? There is closing tags. When I use ctrl:MyControl Name="sad"/>. I still get this warning. Have you any idea?

Comment: everything just look fine..you can try clean solution and build again..

Comment: I rebuild solution and I get this error "Because 'MyControl' is implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute rather than the Name attribute"

Comment: yes that is also thr so just name it using x:Name = "sad"